# Proving a Vector Identity 1.1

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

Assume F, G, H are arbitrary 3D vectors, then

$(\vec{F}$ x $\nabla) . (\vec{G}$ x $\vec{H}) = ((\vec{F}$ x $\nabla)$ x $\vec{G}) . \vec{H} - ((\vec{F}$ x $\nabla)$ x $\vec{H}) . \vec{G}$

I have tried to prove this as you can see here \ref{[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l8eF.jpg)}, what step should i take next or did i do something wrong?

Comment: (1) The sum over $i$ should go away after your third line. Otherwise, your calculation is correct. (2) Hint: start again on from the expression on the right side to arrive at the same expression as you did from the left. This is easier that doing it only one way because there are some terms that cancel when going from the right to your expression.

Comment: (3) Alternative approach: Without using any indices, you can use the formula $(A\times B)\times C = (A\cdot C)B-(B\cdot C)A$ on the right and will eventually get to the left. At least this works if $\nabla$ is just another vector and not a differential operator. But you can argue afterwards that in this specific case the end results holds anyway.